# dynamically resizing UITextView width and height

Tags: ios, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

My code dynamically adjusts according to the text. It increases height when we press enter and 
 increases the width unless we press return.

But how do I make it

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
CGFloat height = [textView.text sizeWithFont:textView.font].height;
CGFloat width =  [textView.text sizeWithFont:textView.font].width;
 if ([[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[text characterAtIndex:text.length-1]])
 {
     self.textViewHeight += height;

     [textView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.contentView.frame.origin.x, self.contentView.frame.origin.y, width, self.textViewHeight)];
     self.contentView.frame = textView.frame;
     self.frame = textView.frame;
     [_editButton setFrame:CGRectMake(self.contentView.frame.size.width - 14, 0, 28, 28)];
   }
    else{

    int charsAsInt = (int)(textView.text.length);
    CGFloat charWidth = width / charsAsInt;

    [textView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.contentView.frame.origin.x, self.contentView.frame.origin.y, width+ charWidth, self.textViewHeight)];
     self.contentView.frame = textView.frame;
     self.frame = textView.frame;
     [_editButton setFrame:CGRectMake(self.contentView.frame.size.width - 14, 0, 28, 28)];


}
```

But it increases width even when I press return. How to prevent that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK the width is width of whole text in all the lines. So have to find a max line length.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
CGFloat height = [textView.text sizeWithFont:textView.font].height;
//CGFloat lineWidth;

int charsAsInt;
 if ([[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[text characterAtIndex:text.length-1]])
 {
     self.lineWidth = 0;
     newLine = @"";
     self.textViewHeight += height;
     NSLog(@"height: %f, width: %f, new Height: %f", height, self.textViewWidth, self.textViewHeight);
     [textView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.contentView.frame.origin.x, self.contentView.frame.origin.y, self.textViewWidth, self.textViewHeight)];
     self.contentView.frame = textView.frame;
     self.frame = textView.frame;
     [_editButton setFrame:CGRectMake(self.contentView.frame.size.width - 14, 0, 28, 28)];

     [super setFrame:textView.frame];
 }
 else{
     newLine = [newLine stringByAppendingString:text];
     self.lineWidth = [newLine sizeWithFont:textView.font].width;
     charsAsInt = (int)(newLine.length);
     CGFloat charWidth = self.lineWidth / charsAsInt;


     if(self.lineWidth >= self.textViewWidth){
         self.textViewWidth = self.lineWidth;
         [textView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.contentView.frame.origin.x, self.contentView.frame.origin.y, self.lineWidth, self.textViewHeight)];
     }

     else{
         [textView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.contentView.frame.origin.x, self.contentView.frame.origin.y, self.textViewWidth, self.textViewHeight)];
     }
     self.contentView.frame = textView.frame;
     self.frame = textView.frame;
     [_editButton setFrame:CGRectMake(self.contentView.frame.size.width - 14, 0, 28, 28)];
     //[super setContentView:self.contentView];
     [super setFrame:textView.frame];
}

return YES;
}
```

Whats happening is We have a multiline UITextView Sticker, so when you press return on your keyboard, you have a new line. Which I'm storing in a new variable now. And the width of whole textVIew is increasing only if width of new line is more than width of old line(`self.textViewWidth`)